# WPF Listview itemtemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tabcontrol with a tab that has a ListView in it that I would like to display a user control I created called "BetterCheckBox". I have bound it to the property `public List<Option> Options { get; set; }` which I have manually added 3 Options to it after initialization.

Here is my XAML

```
<TabItem Header="Options">
    <ListView x:Name="lstOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <Controls:BetterCheckBox Text="{Binding Name}" Description="{Binding Description}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</TabItem>
```

What this produces is a list that appears to be empty, at first I thought my binding wasn't working, however there are 3 very small lines that I can select as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Looks blank but has 3 selections]

For reference, I added my "BetterCheckBox" control to the location tab so you can see what that looks like.

[image]

I was curious so I put a gridview instead, and I got what I was expecting.

[image]

In addition to these tests to try and figure out what's wrong I also tried DataTemplates that used Wrap/Stack Panels and TextBlocks that bound those properties, and they too showed very small lines same as the first screenshot.

```
<TabItem Header="Options">
    <ListView x:Name="lstOptions" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Desc: "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</TabItem>
```

Am I missing something? I'm new to WPF and I feel I'm missing something very simple, or maybe I can't display my usercontrol in this way?

Edit - adding usercontrol as requested:

```
public partial class BetterCheckBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get => _text; set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged("Text"); } }
    public string Description { get => _desc; set { _desc = value; OnPropertyChanged("Description"); } }
    public bool IsChecked { get => _isChecked; set { _isChecked = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _text = "Checkbox Text";
    private string _desc = "Default description";
    private bool _isChecked = false;

    public BetterCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Using DependencyProperty

```
public partial class BetterCheckBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(BetterCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata("Default title")
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Description", typeof(string), typeof(BetterCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata("Default description")
        );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(BetterCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(false)
        );

    public string Text { get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty); set => SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    public string Description { get => (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); set => SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
    public string IsChecked { get => (string)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }

    public BetterCheckBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it shouldn't matter; but for the sake of it; try the root control ```ItemsControl```.  Swap list view out for that completely and let us know the results.

Comment: So it appears when I do that, and use the DataTemplate with the `WrapPanel` it seems to actually display them. When I switch out the wrappanel with my custom control I get the following error: `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Text' property of type 'BetterCheckBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'` Is this an issue with my control and the properties that are on it?

Comment: Yeah, the ```ItemsControl``` is just taking place of the ```ListView``` all else should stay the same.  This just leads me to believe that the ```ListView``` has some default values that aren't being adjusting correctly. I normally just use ```ItemsControl``` when I'm not using the designed behavior of another control but that's not to say you couldn't.

Comment: "*Binding cannot be set on the Text property of type BetterCheckBox*" means that Text is not a dependency property. How does your control look like?

Comment: @Clemens I added it to the post

Comment: Take a look at the [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) article, with special emphasis on the section about dependency properties. When you have converted the properties of your control to dependency properties, also remove `DataContext = this` from its constructor. A custom control with bindable properties must never explicitly set its own DataContext. If you do that, you can't use "normal", DataContext-based Binding on the properties of your control.

Comment: Also note that you do not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for all the help, it now renders without throwing an error, and displays the 3 controls. The only issue is the "Text" property seems to be blank for some reason, description is set properly. ItemsControl is bound to the options list, and the options have a "Name" property and a "Description" property, and in the first example you can see I'm binding to "Name" and "Description", but the Name part doesn't work, am I missing anything else? I also added my control that's now using DependencyProperties at the bottom

Comment: @Clemens that pointed me in the right direction and I got it working now, thank you.